# C++ Can't figure out arrays and functions

Tags: c++, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stuck on C++ functions and arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280921/stuck-on-c-functions-and-arrays)

Stuck on this problem: I can't get it to run and i am stuck on getting the array functions to return to main. Thanks for any help.

Requires the utilization of a 2 dimensional array to store the pounds of food eaten by 3 monkeys each of the seven days of the week.

Create a function to obtain the pounds eaten for each monkey, each day of the week.
Create a second function to determine pass through the array to calculate the total all of the moneys ate, and then the average eaten on one day.

Create a third function to determine which monkey ate the least amount of food and on what day.  Also output the amount the monkey ate on that day.
Create a fourth function to determine which monkey ate the most amount of food on a single day. Output the monkey number, the pounds eaten, and the weekday.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int monkeys = 3;
const int weekdays = 7;
double monkeyWeek[monkeys][weekdays];
double largest;
double least;
double average;
int index;
int dayCount;
double amount;

double amountEaten(double[] [weekdays], int);
double mostEaten (double[] [weekdays],int);
double leastEaten (double[][weekdays], int);

int main(){
    double mostBananas (double[] [weekdays],int);
    double leastBananas (double[][weekdays],int);
    //double bananaAverage (double[][weekdays], int);
}

double amountEaten(double array[] [weekdays], int) {
    cout << "Please enter the amount of food eaten per monkey per day." << endl;
    double amount = array[0][0];
    for (index = 0; index < monkeys; index++)
    {
        for (dayCount = 0; dayCount < weekdays; dayCount++)
        {
            cout << endl << "Please enter the amount of pounds eaten by monkey" 
                         << (index +1)
                         << endl << "for day " << (dayCount +1) << ": ";
            cin >> monkeyWeek[monkeys] [weekdays] ;
            if (monkeyWeek[monkeys] [weekdays] < 1)
                cout << endl <<"Must feed positive amount" << endl;
        }
    }
}

double mostEaten( double array[] [weekdays], int size)
{
    double largest = array[0][0];
    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < count; col++)
        {
            if (array[count][weekdays] > largest)
            largest = array[count][weekdays];
        }
    }
    return largest;
}

double leastEaten(double array[] [weekdays], int size)
{
    double least = array[0][0];

    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < size; col++);
        {
            if (array[count][weekdays] < least)
            least = array[count][weekdays];
        }
    }
    return least;
}
```

Comment: start adding function calls into your main(), in current state your program does nothing. Probably you need help how to call a function?

Answer (score 0):

You are  just  declaring the functions, you haven't made a call to any functions at all. Use the sample below and change your program accordingly.

Example:

```
int main()
{
    int i_array={0,1,2,3,4,5};
    function(i_array);           //  Call a function
    printf("%d",i_array[0]);    // will print 100 not 0
}

void function(int []  i_array)
{
    i_array[0]=100;
}
```